# Dynamical system on a curved space

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a nonholonomic dynamic system as below

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ \theta
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta} & 0 \\
\sin{\theta} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v \\
\omega
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

I wish to know, how can I make it topology dependent if described on chart $(x, y, z) = (u, v, \phi(u, v))$. The picture is a cyclist riding a hill or a cart being maneuvered cliff up.